# change Outlook 2007 to forget password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, password-management

How can I get Outlook to forget my password? Outlook 2007 has saved my password.  I do NOT want password saved, as it is insecure

Comment: you can password protect your pst files for added protection

Comment: What happens if you add an account to Outlook using an incorrect password?

Comment: Do you mean PST or email account password? If account then what Windows version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a way to have Outlook "forget" a password.  The password being saved is by design, allowing you uninterrupted e-mail access.  My suggestion would be to uninstall Outlook (or at least delete your profile) and use your provider's web interface for e-mail management.

Comment: i have always had to enter a password.  Now it is saved - even though I never directed such.  We use Google Apps, so maybe it got saved there.